# Add borders around a flexible handsontable

Tags: css, handsontable

I want to make a handsontable starting from 1 single cell. Then we can add/remove rows/columns by the contexte menu, or even copy-paste data from an Excel file. I fixe the maximum size to be `104 x 66`. So if there are many data, the handsontable will have scrolling.

Now, I want to add borders around the table, for all the cases: 1) when the table does not reach its maximum size, the borders should be JUST around the cells; 2) when the table reaches its maximum size, the borders should be around the maximum size. I have made this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yaxarux/1/edit?html,js,output), which satisfies the second case, but NOT the first one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.9.1/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.9.1/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
  <style>
    .handsontable { border: 1px solid red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example4" class="hot head-gap handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  function getData() {
    return [
      [""]
    ];
  }

  var
    example4 = document.getElementById('example4'),
    hot4;

  hot4 = new Handsontable(example4, {
    data: getData(),
    width: 104,
    height: 66,
    colWidths: 47,
    rowHeights: 23,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: true,
    contextMenuCopyPaste: {
      swfPath: '/bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
    }
  });
});
```

Does anyone have a solution?

**Edit 1:** Following the answer of Serg Chernata:

[image]

**Edit 2:** Following the answer of fap, I see two problems:

1) the red borders are even around the context menu:

[image]

2) the red borders are outside the blue borders of the data:

[image]

Comment: it seems that you didn't fix **max size** of table, but instead you've fixed its **size**, so it's always 104 x 66. So your table won't reach anything since it won't change its dimension. Therefore condition of applying borders in some certain scenarios seems irrelevant.

Comment: The table could contain many data, for example, when I copy-paste a big table from an Excel file. I want to set a limit layout with scrolling for this case.

Comment: Did you play with media queries to solve this?

Comment: @robjez i didn't... i am afraid media queries would complicate the issue, i am wondering if we could realise this within the configuration of hansontable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kinda added some thing and posted in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jidipakowu/edit?html,js,output). I have added css  and included jquery to your original html for dom related queries. Do let me know whether it helps. Here is the JS code.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
function getData() {
return [
  [""]
];
}

var
example4 = document.getElementById('example4'),
hot4;

hot4 = new Handsontable(example4, {
data: getData(),
width: 104,
height: 66,
colWidths: 47,
rowHeights: 23,
rowHeaders: false,
colHeaders: false,
contextMenu: true,
contextMenuCopyPaste: {
  swfPath: '/bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
},
afterRender: function() {
  var item = $('.ht_master.handsontable .wtHolder')[0];
if (item.scrollHeight > item.clientHeight || item.scrollWidth > item.clientWidth) {
    $('.handsontable').css('border', '1px solid red');
    $(item).find('.htCore').css('border', '0px none white');
} else {
    $(item).find('.htCore').css('border', '1px solid red');
}


}
});
});
```

Comment: Is it that you don't want borders around the context menu?

Comment: Then you can remove the `style` element from the html. Do you want an updated JS Bin? Updated the JS Bin.

Comment: nice... this solution is the closest to what I want.

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't answer your question and anything else is also required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your requirements correctly, we can probably do this with a little bit of css:

```
#example4{
  max-width: 104px;
  max-height: 66px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Note, I removed the width and height from your `dandsontable` config. This way we can scale with content up to a certain defined `max-width` and `max-height`.

http://jsbin.com/qehexiyidu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: My bad, remove overflow: scroll. I updated my example. I'm not sure how you want to handle scrolling. http://jsbin.com/qehexiyidu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I do want to keep scrolling, when the table has many cells. That's why I fixed a maximum size. Your example does not permit of scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that, I believe, cover all your requirments by using the after create/remove col/row events, but it's not perfect.

What I did is changing dynamically the Width and Height of the table after one of the events, e.g :

```
hot4.addHook('afterCreateCol', function() {
  setTable();
});
```

If one of or both value are above the limit, they will stay at this limit. (104 x 66 in your example)

So the main function would be :

```
function setTable() {
  if(hot4.getColWidth()*hot4.countCols()<208)
    hot4.updateSettings({
      width: hot4.getColWidth()*hot4.countCols()
    });
  else
    hot4.updateSettings({
      width: 208
    });

  if(hot4.getRowHeight()*hot4.countRows()<132)
    hot4.updateSettings({
      height: hot4.getRowHeight()*hot4.countRows()
    });
  else
    hot4.updateSettings({
      height: 132
    });
}
```

*(I used 208 x 132 for my eyes..)*

Note that I load the data after the creation of the table to trigger the event **afterLoadData**.

The only remaining "issue" (I said it wasn't perfect..) would be the scrollbars. I don't know why, but even if the data fits, the scrollbar are present under the limit. [It's supposed to be fixed](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/331), but apparently not... (I'm very interested if you manage to fix this)

Anyway, I think that starting from this solution, you may succeed to reach exactly what you want so I decided to share it with you in it's current state. You can find a working example in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/madovaloti/edit?html,js,output).

---

Edit 1 : Screenshot of the "Scrollbars issue"

[image]

Even if the 2x2 cells fit in the table, the scrollbars are present.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "even if the data fits, the scrollbar are present under the limit", please see my update...

Comment: Use chrome and you will see what I mean, this is indeed different on Firefox. Also, yep I didn't notice the border for the context menu before, but it's also present in your example within your question. Don't know how I miss that

Comment: Well, you can see my edit, that's what I have with Chrome, but with Firefox I have the same thing than you (Edit 2 : Screenshots of the question)